# How to test get_success_url in ClassBasedView for Django?

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views, django-testing, django-tests

I'm trying to test my success_url method and couldn't find a way to test it correctly and increase my code coverage.

```
#views.py

def get_success_url(self):
    if self.question.type in [
        Question.MULTIPLE_TYPE,
        Question.SINGLE_TYPE
    ]:
        return reverse("question")
    else:
        return reverse("question_answers", kwargs={"id": self.question.pk, "type": Answer.MULTIPLE})
```

This is what I have tried in my tests.py file.

```
#tests.py
from factories import QuestionFactory

def test_get_success_url(self):
    self.client.force_login(user=self.user)
    question = QuestionFactory(owner=self.user)
    if question.type in [
        Question.MULTIPLE_TYPE,
        Question.SINGLE_TYPE
    ]:
        response = self.client.get(reverse("question"))
    else:
        response = self.client.get(
            reverse("question_answers", kwargs={"id": self.question.pk, "type": Answer.MULTIPLE})
        )
    self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to test the get_success_url() method in a CBV, you need to call the CBV itself. So for example:

```
# views.py
class SuccessTestingView(FormView):
    def get_success_url():
        # Your that you want to test here.
```

Tests:

```
# tests.py
from factories import QuestionFactory

    class SuccessfullRedirect(TestCase):

        def test_successfull_redirect_1(self):
            self.client.force_login(user=self.user)
            response = self.client.post(path_to_cbv, criteria_that_leads_to_first_result)
            self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("question"))

        def test_succesfull_redirect_2(self):
            self.client.force_login(user=self.user)
            response = self.client.post(path_to_cbv, criteria_that_leads_to_second_result)
            self.assertRedirects(response, reverse("question_answers", kwargs={"id": self.question.pk, "type": Answer.MULTIPLE}))
```

You need to test the view itself and not the result of the success url call so to speak. Hope that helps.